# How do I fix these error messages on numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Im trying to import numpy into a project i'm doing, but i get the error code:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

When i have tried to go into Python terminal and type

```
"pip install numpy"
```

I get the following error code

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What do i need to do, for this to work?

Comment: The `pip` command you show, does it really include the double-quotes? And that "SyntaxError" you get, that's not the full message output. Without full error message output we can't help you diagnose errors.

Comment: The `SyntaxError` means that you are still in the python shell, your console looks something like `>>> _` after you get the error, right?. Simply open a new terminal and then type `pip install numpy` or `sudo pip install numpy`

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use pip in python terminal. Use bash or cmd or whatevever you have in your OS. Then you can (bash):

```
pip3 install numpy
```

or Powershell:

```
pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use above commands to install numpy

sudo apt-get install python-pip
sudo pip install numpy

Comment: You should probably add a note that those commands are specific to Debian-based Linux distributions.

Comment: Yes ,Thanks to mention it @Someprogrammerdude

Answer (score 0):

firstly `pip --versiyon` and did you see version of pip? If you have pip
Did you try this:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

or

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in command line. Dont use in python.

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

OR

```
python3 -m pip install numpy
```